# Get "webpage is not available" running in a Hyper-V VM - sometimes

Tags: dns, hyper-v

I'm running Windows 7 in a VM under Hyper-V. The host system is Windows Server 2008 R2. It happens about 50% of the time where there are no problems at times, then it happens repeatedly, then clears up again. It's a DNS issue as Chrome reports:

> The server at www.windward.net can't be found, because the DNS lookup
>   failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to
>   its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no
>   connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be
>   caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google
>   Chrome from accessing the network.

Is there something I should turn on/off in the host or VM to eliminate this?

The VM has a static IP address.

??? - thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

I switched the DNS servers on the system from the CenturyLink ones to [the Google ones](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/). That fixed it. Haven't had problems with the CenturyLink ones before (they're my ISP) but I guess they're having problems.